# How to render a canvas gauge data from a Java Script file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a new radial gauge and I am using canvas for this purpose. The data that I have entered inside the canvas tag needs to be placed in another file and then rendered on load of the page. 
    How can I do this? Please help me with it. 
    The following is my code. 
I tried many methods but it is not working for me. I also need to pass data to this to make the pointer move. But I need this functionality to happen first. Please help me.

```
    var gauge = new RadialGauge({
        renderTo: 'canvas-id',
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        //units: "Km/h",
        minValue: 0,
        startAngle: 90,
        ticksAngle: 180,
        valueBox: false,
        maxValue: 100,
        majorTicks: [
            "0",
            "20",
            "40",
            "60",
            "80",
            "100"
        ],
        minorTicks: 4,
        strokeTicks: true,
        borders: true,
        needleType: "arrow",
        needleWidth: 1,
        needleCircleSize: 5,
        needleCircleOuter: true,
        needleCircleInner: true,
        animationDuration: 1500,
        animationRule: "circular"
    }).draw();
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Gauges as Components</title>
        <script src="gauge.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <canvas
        
            data-type="radial-gauge"
            data-width="400"
            data-height="400"
            data-min-value="0"
            data-start-angle="90"
            data-ticks-angle="180"
            data-value-box="false"
            data-max-value="100"
            data-major-ticks="0,20,40,60,80,100"
            data-minor-ticks="4"
            data-stroke-ticks="true"
            data-border-shadow-width="0"
            data-borders="false"
            data-needle-type="arrow"
            data-needle-width="1"
            data-needle-circle-size="5"
            data-needle-circle-outer="true"
            data-needle-circle-inner="true"
            data-animation-duration="1500"
            data-animation-rule="circular"
            ></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```